# Django Rest Framework - Serializer update_or_create giving IntegrityError: Unique Constraint Failed

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am having an issue when using the API to send an update to an existing record.

When I send the API for a new record, it works perfectly. But when I send it for an existing record, I would like it to update the current record, but it just gives me an integrity error instead.

My Serializers.py looks like this:

```
class PartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    part = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = DocumentRef
        fields = ('part', 'field1', 'field2', 'field3')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        part = Part.objects.get(part_number=validated_data['part'])
        validated_data['part'] = part
        return DocumentRef.objects.update_or_create(**validated_data)
```

I have tried changing `update_or_create` to just `create` or just `update` but it will still only work if the record does not exist yet.

The model it should be referencing is DocumentRef, which looks like this:

```
class DocumentRef(models.Model):
    part = models.OneToOneField(Part, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field1 = models.FileField(upload_to='mcp/')
    field2 = models.FileField(upload_to='qcp/')
    field3 = models.FileField(upload_to='cus/')
```

The API View I am using is this:

```
class APIDetailTest(APIView):
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return DocumentRef.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except DocumentRef.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    def get(self, request, pk):
        part = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = PartSerializer(part)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk):
        part = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = PartSerializer(part, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Edit: Changed `create_or_update` to `update_or_create` -- Just made this error in this post, in my code it was correct from the beginning.

Edit2: Have also tried changing the return value to:

`return DocumentRef.objects.update_or_create(defaults={'part_id': part.id}, field1=validated_data['field1'], field2=validated_data['field2'], field3=validated_data['field3'])` but that still gives the `unique constraint failed` error.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a workaround than an answer, but you could try catching the error and treating the request differently.

something like this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    ...
    try: 
        return DocumentRef.objects.create(**validated_data)
    except IntegrityError:
        DocumentRef.objects.filter(part=validated_data['part']).delete()
        return DocumentRef.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

obviously, this is not updating the record. Just deleting the existing one and making a new one.

Comment: Tried this and it did work. And it will work for my needs, but I would rather have the updating working.

Answer (score 0):

Try using it with `defaults` and `kwargs` please read here: [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create)

> The update_or_create method tries to fetch an object from database
> based on the given kwargs. If a match is found, it updates the fields
> passed in the defaults dictionary.

Comment: How would I use kwargs for it? I tried replacing validated_data with **kwargs, but it was then giving me an error: `create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` -- I also tried just setting `defaults=None` but that didn't change anything either. Lastly, I tried specifying each field specifically in the `update_or_create` but that still gives me the unique constraint error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your query like this

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    part = Part.objects.get(part_number=validated_data['part'])
    return DocumentRef.objects.update_or_create(defaults={'part': part}, **validated_data)
```

Comment: Just tried this, and it gives the same error: `UNIQUE constraint failed: mcp_qcp_viewer_documentref.part_id`

Comment: Try updated code.

Comment: I tried making that change. Unfortunately it was still giving me the same error. I tried changing the defaults to `defaults={'part_id':part.id}` and `defaults={'id':part.id}` but I was still getting the same error. I tried removing defaults, and adding `part=part` and also `part_id=part.id` but that gave me the same `unique constraint failed` error.